# Error al subir a una aplicación en ruby on rails a google cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform

Estoy tratando de subir una aplicación hecha en `ruby on rails` a `google cloud`. Estoy siguiendo el siguiente [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/using-cloudsql-postgres) ya que la aplicación usa una base de datos en `postgresql`. Sin embargo, cuando llego al paso ***Deploy a new version*** debo correr el siguiente comando:

```
bundle exec bin/rails assets:precompile
```

Pero luego de correrlo tengo el siguiente error:

```
[dry-types] Dry::Types.module is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version
Use Dry.Types() instead. Beware, it exports strict types by default, for old behavior use Dry.Types(default: :nominal). See more options in the changelog
/home/{user}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `member_types' for #<Dry::Types::Hash::Constructor:0x000055cedb8fd220>
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/dry-types-0.15.0/lib/dry/types/constructor.rb:147:in `method_missing'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/dry-struct-0.5.1/lib/dry/struct/class_interface.rb:306:in `schema'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/dry-struct-0.5.1/lib/dry/struct/class_interface.rb:193:in `check_schema_duplication'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/dry-struct-0.5.1/lib/dry/struct/class_interface.rb:133:in `attributes'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/dry-struct-0.5.1/lib/dry/struct/class_interface.rb:113:in `attribute'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator_text/types/sentence.rb:8:in `<class:Sentence>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator_text/types/sentence.rb:3:in `<module:Types>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator_text/types/sentence.rb:2:in `<module:TranslatorText>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator_text/types/sentence.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator_text/types.rb:30:in `require_relative'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator_text/types.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator-text.rb:4:in `require_relative'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/translator-text-0.1.0/lib/translator-text.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/{user}/projects/consul/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/{user}/projects/consul/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/{user}/projects/consul/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Alguien sabe a que se puede deber esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Alguna idea? :c

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que sea un error de la gema [`translator-text`](https://github.com/PerfectMemory/translator-text).
No se si la habrás elegido tú, pero como lección para la próxima, al momento de agregar una gema a tu proyecto, revisa que tanta mantención recibe, como cantidad de commits (8 en ésta) la antiguedad del último commit (casi 2 años ya sin actualizaciones), cuantos colaboradores tiene (solo uno, el creador), que tantos issues abiertos/resueltos tiene (0/0), etc.
Personalmente, la cambiaría por [`bing_translator-gem`](https://github.com/relrod/bing_translator-gem) que parece tener mucho más soporte de la comunidad.
Si cambiar la gema no es una opción, reporta el problema en [la página del proyecto](https://github.com/PerfectMemory/translator-text/issues/new) a ver si recibes respuesta.
Si eso no resulta, no quedará otra más que crear un fork del proyecto, empezar a usar el fork en tu proyecto y entrar a corregir la gema por ti mismo. Suerte!